# How to bundle typescript files for the browser user gulp and tsproject?

Tags: typescript, gulp, frontend, bundling-and-minification

I'm kinda new to front end development, being a long time backend C# and Java developer, and I'm trying to come to grips with how to *build* front end applications. I would like to build an application using typescript and use gulp for my build pipeline to transpile, bundle and minify my code to a single JavaScript file.

For this purpose, I have been looking at the node module [tsproject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsproject) which, as far as I can understand, is supposed to do exactly what I want. Except, I can't get it to do what I want :-(.

This is the relevant parts my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');
var tsproject = require('tsproject');

gulp.task('default', [ 'min-js' ]);

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return gulp
        .src('./dist/', { read: false })
        .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('min-js', [ 'clean' ], function () {
    return tsproject
        .src('./tsconfig.json')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'))
});
```

And my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react",
        "outDir": "./"
    },
    "files": [
        "./src/**/*.tsx",
        "./src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "bundles": {
        "myApp": {
            "files": [
                "./src/App.tsx"
            ],
            "config": {
                "minify": true,
                "sourcemap": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I had expected this to output a single js-file containing transpiled, bundled and minified JavaScript code but what I get is a bundled (not transpiled nor minified) Typescript file (./dist/js/myApp.min.ts).

Am I doing something wrong or have I completely misunderstood the purpose and intent of tsproject?

Comment: If I may offer a suggestion, look into the Angular 2 CLI. It uses Webpack to do all of this with VERY little effort (like the least effort I've ever seen). Using four commands, you can create, serve, test, and build a really robust front end project using TypeScript and Angular 2. In a way I think the CLI is a little unfair since it makes building and working with a project braindead easy.

If you look me up online you may think I have a vested motive here, but I really don't. The Angular 2 CLI is just one of the finest UI dev utils I've seen in my quarter century in the field.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Tim, though I'm not really interested in using Angular. I'm currently looking at using React which IMHO looks easier to work with.

Comment: I get that, what I was suggesting is that as a learning tool it might be useful to see how it gets set up and such. 

Or, maybe take a look at plain old Webpack. Here's a React-specific article:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it but I finally got things working with a gulpfile like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('default', [ 'min-js' ]);

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return gulp
        .src([
            './tmp/',
            './dist/'
        ], { read: false })
        .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('transpile-ts', ['clean'], function () {
    var tsproject = ts.createProject('./src/tsconfig.json');
    return tsproject
        .src()
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(tsproject()).js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./sourcemaps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp/js'));
});

gulp.task('min-js', [ 'transpile-ts' ], function () {
    return gulp
        .src('./tmp/js/App.js')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
        .pipe(browserify())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(concat('App.min.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./sourcemaps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'))
});
```

Basically I transpile all TypeScript files to Javascript with CommonJS imports to a temporary directory. Then I use Browserify to bundle (i.e. resolve the CommonJS imports) the JavaScript files into a single file. Finally I minify the resulting JavaScript file. Voila!

For some reason I had to first write the transpiled files to a temporary directory and then bundle and minify those files. Instead of just keep on pipeing the result of `pipe(tsproject())` to `browserify()`...

Answer (score 0):

Updated David Nordvall's answer with latest GULP specification which has tasks set as exports:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const {series} = require('gulp');
const clean = require('gulp-clean');
const ts = require('gulp-typescript');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

function cleanAll(cb) {
  return gulp.src([
      "./tmp/",
      "./dist/"
    ], { read: false, allowEmpty: true })
    .pipe(clean());
}

function transpileTS() {
  const tsproject = ts.createProject('./tsconfig.json');
  return tsproject
      .src()
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(tsproject()).js
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./sourcemaps'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp/js'));
}

function minJS() {
  return gulp
      .src('./tmp/js/App.js')
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
      .pipe(browserify())
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(concat('App.min.js'))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./sourcemaps'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'))
}

exports.default = series( cleanAll, transpileTS, minJS );
```