# Convert Typescript files into single javascript file for browser with gulp

Tags: javascript, typescript, browser, gulp, bundling-and-minification

All i want to do is take my typescript files and convert them into a single javascript file that will work in a browser using gulp.

NOTE: I cannot use webpack like i wanted because i also have angular-cli installed and you cannot install both webpack and angular-cli using the same package.json file else it breaks!

My typescript files are also using `paths` via tsconfig.json file, and everytime i try to convert the files, i get an error saying that a module cannot be found because its imports looks something like this (in typescript)

```
import { ModuleName } from '@my_path:/dir/to/my/class';
```

I am also getting errors like this

> error TS2693: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a
>   value here

Someone please help, i have looked on internet and no matter what example i try, it always ends up erroring.  I cannot upload the files as far to many.

I have even looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40845287/2736022) but still not help.

My gulp file looks like this

```
// gulp methods
const gulp = require('gulp');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const hash = require('gulp-hash-filename');
const del = require('del');
const sourceMaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

// typescript
const ts = require('gulp-typescript');

// paths
const jsDest = '../wwwroot/htmltopdf';

// clean the contents of the distribution directory
gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return del('../wwwroot/htmltopdf/**/*', { force: true });
});

// build typescript
gulp.task('ts', function(){
    const tsProject = ts.createProject('./tsconfig.json');

    return tsProject.src()
        .pipe(sourceMaps.init())
        .pipe(tsProject())
        .pipe(sourceMaps.write())
        .pipe(concat('htmltopdf.js'))
        // .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDest));
});

gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'ts']);
```

Here is my `tsconfig.json` file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/htmltopdf",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "noResolve": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "paths": {
      "@shared:/*": ["../../shared/src/*"],
      "@models:/*": ["../../shared/models/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "main.ts",
    "../../shared/src/report/**/*.builder.ts",
    "../../shared/models/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "../ClientApp"
  ]
}
```

But here is one of my typescript files

```
import {DatasheetBuilder} from '@shared:/report/datasheet/datasheet.builder';
import {CrossTabBuilder} from '@shared:/report/cross-tab/cross-tab.builder';
import {ChartBuilder} from '@shared:/report/chart/chart.builder';
import {PictogramBuilder} from '@shared:/report/pictogram/pictogram.builder';
import {ScoringGridBuilder} from '@shared:/report/scoring-grid/scoring-grid.builder';
import {FileStripBuilder} from '@shared:/report/file-strip/file-strip.builder';

(window as any).DatasheetBuilder = DatasheetBuilder;
(window as any).CrossTabBuilder = CrossTabBuilder;
(window as any).ChartBuilder = ChartBuilder;
(window as any).PictogramBuilder = PictogramBuilder;
(window as any).ScoringGridBuilder = ScoringGridBuilder;
(window as any).FileStripBuilder = FileStripBuilder;
```

And in my generated javascript, it generates this, which is wrong because the path is still using my tsconfig path variable

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var datasheet_builder_1 = require("@shared:/report/datasheet/datasheet.builder");
var cross_tab_builder_1 = require("@shared:/report/cross-tab/cross-tab.builder");
var chart_builder_1 = require("@shared:/report/chart/chart.builder");
var pictogram_builder_1 = require("@shared:/report/pictogram/pictogram.builder");
var scoring_grid_builder_1 = require("@shared:/report/scoring-grid/scoring-grid.builder");
var file_strip_builder_1 = require("@shared:/report/file-strip/file-strip.builder");
window.DatasheetBuilder = datasheet_builder_1.DatasheetBuilder;
window.CrossTabBuilder = cross_tab_builder_1.CrossTabBuilder;
window.ChartBuilder = chart_builder_1.ChartBuilder;
window.PictogramBuilder = pictogram_builder_1.PictogramBuilder;
window.ScoringGridBuilder = scoring_grid_builder_1.ScoringGridBuilder;
window.FileStripBuilder = file_strip_builder_1.FileStripBuilder;
```

Comment: I think you want `--outFile`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: @peinearydevelopment using that gives me `Only 'amd' and 'system' modules are supported alongside --outFile.`